# Pass Cognito User Info to HTTP Integration

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I've been exploring utilizing Cognito User Pools for authentication and API Gateway to feed client requests with auth tokens. I'd basically like to have a simple react app that utilizes the cognito sdk for authentication. Then use the authentication to make requests via the API Gateway to an express application, hooked up to cognito user pool auth. It would be ideal to have user information available in the express app - seems pretty simple to me.

I've seen many articles and forum posts about how to retrieve Cognito User Info in the context of a lambda function but nothing about how to retrieve Cognito User Info in the context of an HTTP Integration.

Is this possible?

Comment: Basically I’d like to know if the same applies to non lambda endpoints: After validating the JWT, API Gateway passes the claims in the token to the API route’s integration. Backend resources, such as Lambda functions, can access the JWT claims. For example, if the JWT includes an identity claim emailID, it's available to a Lambda integration in $event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.emailID. For more information about the payload that API Gateway sends to Lambda integrations, see Working with AWS Lambda proxy integrations for HTTP APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and can be achieved in, at least, two ways:

#### Proxying requests with original headers

If you enable "Use HTTP Proxy integration" in your HTTP integration, the API Gateway will act as a proxy and forward any headers in the request to the backend (and same from the backend response back to the client). This means that the JWT will reach the express application in the same header the client sent it, where it can be decoded and the claim(s) retrieved.

#### Using request [and response] data mappings

Another way is to pass the required claim(s) in the Path/QueryString/Headers mappings for the Integration Request, using `context.authorizer.claims.{claim}` in the mapping, e.g. `context.authorizer.claims.email`. You can see the documentation on [setting up the data mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html) and also the [mapping reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html) for more variables that can be used. Please note that for [context variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) the right syntax to use is without the `$` prefix.